# How to split words in Camel Case with special capital words inside?

Tags: string, split, camelcasing

I am trying to make configuration names easier to understand for my deep learning model. The first thing I am supposed to do is to split the configuration names into tokens. 
The input is like:

```
allow-nonxdr-writes
io.native.lib.available
ha.zookeeper.parent-znode
min_file_size
ProxyStatus
ProxyFCGIBackendType
SessionDBDCookieRemove
DBDriver
SSLOCSPDefaultResponder
```

The corresponding output should be:

```
allow nonxdr writes
io native lib available
ha zookeeper parent znode
min file size
Proxy Status
Proxy FCGI Backend Type
Session DBD Cookie Remove
DB Driver
SSL OCSP Default Responder
```

As shown above, the format of the configuration names varies(Since they come from different software of different organizations). For the first 4 names it's okay to split them by delimiter like `.`,`-` or `_`. The last five is quite tough for me to handle. If I split these names just by Camel-Case principal with words started with a capital letter, words with special meanings like `FCGI`,`DBD`,`DB` may be wrongly split.

Is there any good practice suitable to handle this problem? Is building a dictionary manually the only way to this problem?

BTW. This situation only occurs when dealing with configuration names in Apache Httpd.

Comment: For the input `SSLOCSPDefaultResponder` there is no way we can know to split the first part into `SSL` and `OCSP`.  You need to provide rules for this.

Comment: It will help a lot if there is a way to split the rest names. It's acceptable if the last input cannot be split properly. I just mentioned this for further discussion. @tim

Comment: I have attempted an answer below, which gets close to what you want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex pattern seems to get close:

```
[-._]|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])
```

Explanation:

```
[-._]                     split on -, ., or _
|                         OR
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])       split when lowercase precedes and uppercase follows
|                         OR
(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])  split when uppercase precedes followed by upper-lower
```

### Demo

The only test input which does not match what you expect is:

```
SSLOCSPDefaultResponder
```

My regex gives:

```
SSLOCSP Default Responder
```

The reason for this is that there is no clear rule by which we would know that a break should occur between `SSL` and `OCSP`.  If you want that logic, you might need to keep a dictionary of known "words" around which there should be additional splits.

Comment: This is quite close to the answer that I'm looking for!